# How to toggle multiple elements with same class name on click

Tags: javascript, html, css, onclick, toggle

How can I change the color from green to red to all the line when I click the toggle button . It doesn't seem to work with same class name if I use **getElementsbyClassName** or **querySelectorAll** , only the first line color changes if I use **querySelector** . All the line color changes if I give each paragraph a different id or class name .So basically how can I toggle multiple elements with same class name (in this case class name is **'para'**) on click ? Here is my **codepen** link - https://codepen.io/fahim04blue/pen/KKNvOZe

**html**-

```
<button id='btn' type="button" class="btn btn-primary">toggle</button>
<br>
<br>
<div>
  <p class="para">Paragraph 1</p>
  <p class="para">Paragraph 2</p>
  <p class="para">Paragraph 3</p>
  <p class="para">Paragraph 4</p>
</div>
```

**CSS** -

```
.para{
  background-color:green;
}

.para.red{
  background-color:red;
}
```

**Vanilla JS**

```
const btn = document.getElementById('btn');
const para = document.querySelector('.para');

btn.addEventListener('click',()=>{
  para.classList.toggle('red');
})
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are selecting only one element, change `querySelector` to `querySelectorAll` and then use a loop.

```
const btn = document.getElementById('btn');
const para = document.querySelectorAll('.para');

btn.addEventListener('click',()=>{
  para.forEach(el => {
    el.classList.toggle('red');
  })
})
```

Comment: That's a step back from jQuery, will we need loops scattered all over the place? I was looking for some simple oneliner to toggle few elements, turned out that in vanilla js it is impossible, need loop.

Answer (score 0):

```
const btn = document.getElementById('btn');
const para = document.querySelectorAll('.para');

btn.addEventListener('click',()=>{
  para.forEach(p => p.classList.toggle('red'));
})
```

you should use forEach() to change all the elements of the class.